# need help converting windows notifcation to text-to-speach in python

Tags: python, automation, text-to-speech

Is there any way in which I could get the info/text of a notification example if there comes a notification I want to be able to get that as a string to further make it a text-to-speech

Comment: I recommend using **PIL** to get the image of notification and **OCR (Optical Character Recognition)** to get the text from the image. Probably, it will provide you some flexibility for your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a python script to convert text to speach using the gtts and playsound library.

```
import gtts 
from playsound import playsound  #https://pypi.org/project/playsound/

#Load the string into gtts   
tts = gtts.gTTS("STRINGTOCONVERTTOAUDIO")
filename = "audio.mp3"
#Remove the audio file if already exists
os.remove(filename)   
# save the audio file to a convenient location... 
tts.save(filename)
# play the audio file
playsound(filename)
```

And then you could call upon this script/function wherever you need it on whichever operating system.

Comment: yes I could do that I know how to do that but how do I get a notification as a text